# Using a fix $key and variable $data vs partially variable $key with fixed $data in PHP's hash_hmac()

Tags: php

This question was originally asked in stack overflow, but it was suggested to ask it here as well..

- not looking to improve on hash_hmac functionality. I'm rather interested in the `$uri` in the examples below..

The theory is that typically we create signed URI's like

```
$superSecret = 'abc';
$data = 'https://localhost/verify/{user-id}/{email}';
$hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $data, $superSecret);

$uri = $data . '/?hash=' . $hash;
```

Then we can validate the signature by recreating a hash, and calling `hash_equals()`. If any of part of the data string changed, `hash_equal()` returns false.

What happens if we switch some parameters around. This time instead of hashing different data, we hash the same data every time but with different keys.

I.e.

```
$superSecret = 'abc' . $userId . $email;
$data = 'https://localhost/verify';
$hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $data, $superSecret);

$uri  = $data;
```

The above are dumbed down generalized examples. But I'm more interested in, is the concept correct? Would using different keys to hash the same data be as secure as using different data hashed by the same key.

Keep in mind that the 'abc' of `$superSecret` is never exposed. `$user-id` and `$email` are concatenated onto the end of `$superSecret`

The original question for those interested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60401068/is-using-a-variable-key-with-constant-data-as-secure-as-using-a-constant-key-wit

Comment: I'll let someone else give a more comprehensive answer, but as a general rule of thumb it is best to use things as-intended.  In other words, let the key just be the key, and let the data be the data.  Using them as they are not intended *may* not cause direct security concerns, but that doesn't mean it is a good idea, especially since it will violate the [principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Comment: The most relevant concern I can think of is that some algorithms may have a maximum key length.  In fact, I think all do, but in many cases this is circumvented by hashing the key if it is too long.

Comment: @ConorMancone I would argue (constructively) you are correct in regards to traditional signed URI's. But in respect to `hash_hmac()` that argument falls short, as the key is still a key, as is the data. The only difference is what I am using to formulate a key and not changing the data being hashed. If that makes sense..

Comment: That's not quite true though.  The userid and email are the things that need to be verified, and therefore by definition they are the data.  Sure, they are being passed in as the key, and things might not obviously break, but the data and key are being used contrary to their intended purpose.  If nothing else this will confuse further developers later: "I'm migrating to a new system and made sure to copy the key exactly, but signature verification failed.  I don't understand what's wrong??".  If nothing else you want to avoid **that**.

Comment: for hmac it shouldn't matter like it would with some symmetric schemes because both args are (among other things) XOR'd in a non-reversible way.